# Converting SVG files to GeoJSON

Tags: geojson, convert, svg

I am struggling with converting SVG files (with geographic coordinate metadata) into a GeoJSON file. I have been trying the [svg2geojson](https://github.com/Phrogz/svg2geojson) command line util and online conversion tool [MyGeodata Cloud](https://mygeodata.cloud/).

Both give me errors with the upper case "S" that I have in my outline letters of the word "YES".

The svg2geojson says:

> "Our deepest apologies, but elliptical arc commands (A) are not yet
> supported."

And mygeodata.cloud just gives:

> "No spatial data were recognized in your uploaded data."

Although I do have spatial data and if I take out the "S" (the last path) - it works! Maybe I am missing something or there is a better way? The file is here (since I can't attach):

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 70.23 33.36">
<MetaInfo xmlns="http://www.prognoz.ru"><Geo>
  <GeoItem X="-595.30" Y="-142.88" Latitude="36.738688" Longitude="-116.004639"/>
  <GeoItem X="1388.66" Y=" 622.34" Latitude="36.725883" Longitude="-115.977516"/>
</Geo></MetaInfo>
<path d="M10.23,32.88V19.15L0,.53H4.75L9.31,9.46c1.25,2.44,2.21,4.41,3.22,6.67h.09c.92-2.11,2-4.23,3.27-6.67L20.55.53H25.3L14.45,19.11V32.88Z"/>
<path d="M45.41,17.71H32.83V29.38h14v3.5H28.66V.53H46.13V4H32.83V14.26H45.41Z"/>
<path d="M51.7,27.79a14.69,14.69,0,0,0,7.48,2.12c4.28,0,6.77-2.26,6.77-5.52,0-3-1.73-4.76-6.09-6.44-5.28-1.87-8.55-4.6-8.55-9.17,0-5,4.18-8.78,10.47-8.78a14.77,14.77,0,0,1,7.15,1.58L67.78,5a13,13,0,0,0-6.15-1.53c-4.41,0-6.09,2.64-6.09,4.84,0,3,2,4.52,6.43,6.25,5.47,2.11,8.26,4.75,8.26,9.5,0,5-3.7,9.31-11.33,9.31a16.76,16.76,0,0,1-8.26-2.06Z"/>
</svg>
```